# Re-Writing user-defined function with While Loop

Tags: r, function, while-loop

I'm writing the following function that is supposed to compute the value of an intensity function at the seed.times.

```
Intensity=function(params, eval.times, event.times) {
 # This function computes the value of the intensity function.
 # It takes as seed a vector of values/times at which to compute the 
 # the value of the function and a vector with the occurrence times
 # of the events. 

 # Input: eval.times, event.times and values of parameters
 # Output: values of intensity function

 s<-sort(eval.times)
 t<-sort(event.times)
 par1<-params[1]
 par2<-params[2]
 par3<-params[3]

 values <- rep(par1,length(s))
 for (i in 1:length(values)) {
     j<-1
     while (t[j] < s[i])
     {
             values[i] <- values[i] + par2*exp(-par3*(s[i]-t[j]))
             j <- j+1
      }
    }   

 return(values)
}
```

However, when I run it in R I get the following error: `Error in while (t[j] < s[i]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. What does it mean? The above function is actually my attempt to improve on my original function written as

```
Intensity=function(params, eval.times, event.times) {
# This function computes the value of the intensity function.
# It takes as seed a vector of values/times at which to compute the 
# the value of the function and a vector with the occurence times
# of the events. 

# Input: eval.times, event.times and values of parameters
# Output: values of intensity function

s<-sort(eval.times)
t<-sort(event.times)
par1<-params[1]
par2<-params[2]
par3<-params[3]

values<-foreach(i=seq_along(s), .combine=c) %do% {par1+sum(par2*exp(-par3*(s[i]-t[which(t<s[i])])))}


return(values)
```

}

in which I want to substitute the `sum` and `which` with a `while` loop since my arrays are ordered times and can get pretty long. Any suggestions?

As suggested, let me post the data that produces the error:

`event1<-c(3580.794 3583.079 3583.714 3583.998 3584.116 3585.042 3586.264)`
`seed.times1<-seq(3580, 3590, by=0.001)`

`hintensity1<-Intensity(c(0.1,5,17), seed.times1, event1)`

`Error in while (t[j] < s[i]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: Post some example data that throws the error.

Comment: If I run the function using `which` and `sum` on the same data I don't get the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the value of t[j] and s[j] at the point where the error is thrown, I suspect you'll find that one of the two is NA.  More specifically, I think it's t[j].  And that's because you allow the index j to grow without bounds, so at some point you'll exceed the number of elements in your t vector.  Try including an additional condition in your where() control.  I don't know what you want to happen when all the elements of t are exhaustive, but something like this might work:

```
event1<-c(3580.794, 3583.079, 3583.714, 3583.998, 3584.116, 3585.042, 3586.264) 
seed.times1<-seq(3580, 3590, by=0.001)

Intensity=function(params, eval.times, event.times) {
 # This function computes the value of the intensity function.
 # It takes as seed a vector of values/times at which to compute the 
 # the value of the function and a vector with the occurrence times
 # of the events. 

 # Input: eval.times, event.times and values of parameters
 # Output: values of intensity function

 s<-sort(eval.times)
 t<-sort(event.times)
 par1<-params[1]
 par2<-params[2]
 par3<-params[3]

 values <- rep(par1,length(s))
 for (i in 1:length(values)) {
     j<-1
     while (!is.na(t[j]) && t[j] < s[i])
     {
         values[i] <- values[i] + par2*exp(-par3*(s[i]-t[j]))
         j <- j+1
      }
    }   

 return(values)
}

hintensity1<-Intensity(c(0.1,5,17), seed.times1, event1)
```

Comment: nice, that seems to do the trick! You have also suggested me to " inspect the value of t[j] and s[j] at the point where the error is thrown" which is a great idea, but how can I do this?

Comment: One way would be to use a print() function, perhaps right after you invoke the while... loop, or right before the end of the loop after you update your j index.  Something like print(t[j]); print(s[i]);
That way at least you'll see what the values are right before you error out (if there is an error).  I'd recommend using this for debugging purposes only, since if your loop runs a larger number of times, it may fill your screen.